# Calling CSS style file from input tag

Tags: html, css, jsp

I am creating a form on the client side there is a JSP page and on the server side I am using Java servlets to process the data. What I am trying to do is that if there is an error I want to be able to pass an error message which will cause the input get a red line under it to indicate an error. My code below works perfectly:

```
<input type="email" name="email" id="email" value="${param.email}" class="validate" <c:if test="${ not empty emailError}">style="border-bottom: 2.5px solid red; "</c:if>>
<label for="email" data-error="${emailError }" data-success="">Email</label>
```

What I want to know is, is there a way to remove `style="border-bottom: 2.5px solid red; "` and replace it with a css file. The reason I want to do this is because I will have hundreds of lines of code with that specific style, if I ever wanted to change the style to something else I would need to go through every page and replace everything line by line. So can I store this style in a separate file and just call on that file to create the same effect? I am doing this for easy maintenance.

I also want to note that I can't just add this to the style sheet because then all the inputs will have a red line under them, I only want a input to show a red line if there is an error with that specific input.

Comment: Are you using some kind of client side reactive JS library? What's `${emailError }`, etc.?

Comment: that a parameter to from the server side (Java) I would do `request.setAttribute("emailError", "error")` . And this way  `${emailError}` will have a value and the style will be set for the input tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure about the JSP way of yours, to check the correctness of the code. What I would simply do is:

1. Create a CSS class called `.error` and define it with `{border-bottom: 2px solid red;}`. Note that, [`px` is always integer](http://cruft.io/posts/percentage-calculations-in-ie/).
2. Secondly, I will use AJAX to return any data for validating them.

> ***Note:*** ps: Sorry I am using [jQuery library](http://jquery.com), which is awesome, and you haven't said that in your OP.

Let me show you a simple way to do this:

```js
$(function () {
  $("#numcheck").keyup(function () {
    $this = $(this);
    $.post("/path/to/check.jsp", function (res) {
      if (res != "OK")
        $this.addClass("error");
      else
        $this.removeClass("error");
    });
  });
});
```

```css
* {font-family: 'Segoe UI';}
.error {border-bottom: 2px solid red;}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="numcheck" />
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, your solution did not exactly work but I was able to take some ideas you gave me and come up with another solution.

Comment: @develop1 Awesome... All the best. `:)`

Answer (score 1):

Praveen Kumar had a really good idea of creating a `.error` class. what I ended up doing was:

```
<input type="email" name="email" id="email" value="${param.email}" class="validate" onclick="inputClicked('email')">
<label for="email" data-error="${emailError }" data-success="">Email</label>

<c:if test="${ not empty emailError}">
   <script type="text/javascript">
        javascript:error('email');
    </script></c:if>
```

And the Javascript error(...) method :

```
<script>
window.error = function(name) {

  document.getElementById(name).style.borderBottom = "solid red";
}
</script>
```

To remove the style:

```
<script>

function inputClicked(name){
      $("#"+name).removeAttr("style")
};
</script>
```

Comment: This looks good. I am voting it up. `:)` I am still wondering, how would you remove the style, if the input is good?

Comment: I created another javascript method which removed the style, I will add the code.